# Accept number or character

Tags: string, lisp, common-lisp, clisp

I know I can use `(every #'digit-char-p str)` to check if every character is an digit or `(every #'alpha-char-p str)` if it is a character. The problem is that I want to accept if the word contains letters or number but not symbols like +. Hello1 should return true but not Hello1-. Anyone knows how to do that?

Comment: You can use the predicate `alphanumericp` (see the [manual](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_alphan.htm#alphanumericp)).

Answer (score 1):

`every`'s first argument is a function (in fact a function designator): you can put any function you want there.  In this case, as mentioned in a comment, there's a function defined by the language which does what you want, but if there wasn't you could write one:

```
(every (lambda (c) (or (digit-char-p c) (alpha-char-p c))) ...)
```

or `(every (lambda (c) (and (explodablep c) (green c))) ...)`.  Or anything you want.